# Stable harmonic mean of two 3x3 matrices

Tags: matrices, inverse

I am looking for a stable formula to compute the harmonic mean of two 3×3 matrices, tolerant to singular matrices.

For 1×1 matrices, we know that $(a^{-1}+b^{-1})^{-1}=\frac{a b}{a+b}$, which does not fail if either $a$ or $b$ are zero.

For 2×2 matrices, we know that $(A^{-1}+B^{-1})^{-1}=\frac{A \det B+B \det A}{\det(A+B)}$, which does not fail if either $A$ or $B$ are singular.

For 3×3 matrices, I suspect a formula of the form
$$
(A^{-1}+B^{-1})^{-1}=\frac{A \det B+B \det A+\text{something}}{\det(A+B)}
$$

Answer (score 1):

One way of expressing the inverse-sum-of-inverses of two 3×3 matrices is
$$
\newcommand{\adj}{\text{adj}}
\newcommand{\cadj}{\text{cadj}}
(A^{-1}+B^{-1})^{-1} = \frac{A\det B+B\det A+\adj(\adj A+\adj B)-\adj\adj A-\adj\adj B}{\det(A+B)}\\
=\frac{\adj(\adj A+\adj B)-(\det A-\det B)(A-B)}{\det(A+B)}\\
=\frac{A\det B+B\det A+\cadj(\adj A,\adj B)}{\det(A+B)}
$$
where $\adj$ is the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix),
$\adj\adj A=A\det A$, and $\cadj$ is the cross-adjugate matrix
$$
\cadj(U,V)=\adj(U+V)-\adj U-\adj V.
$$